# Conversion from type LINQ Result to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, linq

I created a Form with ComboBox to search and 4 TextBoxes to view fields value. I used `Form_load` event to fill the ComboBox.

Here is my code:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Linq

Public Class FRM_Product
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connection string)
    Dim db As New ProductDataContext(connection)

    Private Sub FRM_ Product_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
        MyBase.Load
        Dim V_Query = db.Product_Write(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing).ToList
        If V_Query.Count <> 0 Then
            CMB_Search.DataSource = V_Query
            CMB_Search.ValueMember = "Product_ID"
            CMB_Search.DisplayMember = "Product_A"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CMB_Search_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CMB_Search.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim ID As Integer = CMB_Search.SelectedValue

        Dim V_Query = db.Product_Write(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing).ToList
        TXT_Product_ID.Text = V_Query(0). Product_ID
        TXT_ Product_A.Text = V_Query(0). Product_A
        TXT_ Product_E.Text = V_Query(0). Product_E
        TXT_ Product_NOTE.Text = V_Query(0). Product_Note
    End Sub
```

And here's the `Product_Write` stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Product_Write 
    @ Product_ID   INT = NULL , 
    @ Product_A    nvarchar(50)= NULL , 
    @ Product_E    nvarchar(50)= NULL , 
    @ Product_Note nvarchar(255)= NULL 
AS 
    BEGIN 
        SET NOCOUNT ON; 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT * 
            FROM [dbo].[ Product] 
            WHERE [Product_ID] = ISNULL( @Product_ID,[Product_ID]) 
              AND [Product_A] = ISNULL( @Product_A,[Product_A]) 
              AND [Product_E] = ISNULL( @Product_E, [Product_E]) 
            ORDER BY [Product_A] 
        END 
    END
```

The line

```
Dim ID As Integer = CMB_Search.SelectedValue
```

is causing this error:

> Conversion from type ' Product_WriteResult' to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

How to fix this error?

Comment: Which line throws this exception?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
Dim myDataRowView As DataRowView = DirectCast(CMB_Search.SelectedValue, DataRowView)
Dim ID as Integer = CInt(myDataRowView("Product_ID"))
```